# Mac VBA | Excel / Powerpoint 2016 (Vers. 15.33) | Powerpoint crashes on Shapes.AddTextBox method

Tags: vba, macos, excel, powerpoint

I am coding VBA in excel, which attempts to open and save a copy of a Powerpoint file, then add a textbox to a slide.

Run in a Mac environment, the below code succeeds in opening and saving the ppt file, but on the With statement where it tries to call the AddTextbox method, it causes the Powerpoint Application to crash. (EXC_BAD_ACCESS error)

I have no problem opening Powerpoint files and it crashes only when I ran this code. My suspicion is either the Shapes.AddTextbox method or some of its parameters are not supported, but I couldn't find relevant information/ reference on the internet.

Many thanks if someone can shed light on this. In addition, in the view that VBA is not as well-supported in Mac vs in Windows, is there other alternatives to Powerpoint automation (say Applescript)?

```
Option Explicit
Public Const COVER_SLIDE = 3
Dim param_ws As Worksheet

Sub Main()
    Set param_ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Param")

    'Open the template Powerpoint, save as a copy
    Dim PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation

    Set PowerPointApp = New PowerPoint.Application
    Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open(param_ws.Range("wk_dir").Value & "/" & param_ws.Range("ppt_temp_fileName").Value)
    myPresentation.SaveAs (param_ws.Range("wk_dir").Value & "/" & param_ws.Range("myfolder").Value & "/" & param_ws.Range("myfile").Value)

    PowerPointApp.Visible = True

    ' ##################   All good until here   ##################
    With myPresentation.Slides(COVER_SLIDE).Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=Application.InchesToPoints(5.71), Top:=Application.InchesToPoints(3.8), Width:=Application.InchesToPoints(3.47), Height:=Application.InchesToPoints(1.04))
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Hello"
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 28
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial Narrow"
        .TextFrame.HorizontalAnchor = msoAnchorCenter
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignRight
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more a comment than an answer, but comment formatting would make a hash of it, so here we are.

First, I'd change

Public Const COVER_SLIDE = 3

to

Public Const COVER_SLIDE as Long = 3

It's generally best to TELL vba what you want rather than letting it guess. In this case, it *shouldn't* make any difference, but there are some strange bugs running around under the covers in Mac VBA.

I'd also verify that Mac Excel (in the version you're running) actually does have an Application.InchesToPoints method. If not, it's simple enough to multiply your inches values by 72 when you add the text box.

Finally, ppAlignRight is a PowerPoint constant, not an Office-wide or Excel constant, so it won't be defined, and in fact, should cause an error when you compile your code in the IDE (always a good idea before trying to run it).  Either define it as:

```
Public Const ppAlignRight as Long = 3
```

or use 3 instead of ppAlignRight in your code.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for your comment. Appreciate your advice on the Public Const line and checking the InchesToPoints method. 

On the ppAlignRight though, I believe if one has added the Powerpoint library reference to the module, it should be able to recognize ppAlignRight? (This is the case when I ran my code in Windows, correct me if i'm wrong)

Comment: If you've added a reference to the PPT library, I'd edit your original question to mention that, though your variable declarations make that evident, now that you mention it). It *should* recognize the PPT constants, in that case, yes.